# Установка opencv и python на mac

Tags: python, macos, mac, opencv

На днях приобрел себе mac, начал устанавливать opencv и возникли проблемы.

Устанавливал через brew, но python не импортирует cv2. На c++ заработал посредством установки через cmake и ручного указания файлов.

Помогите разобраться, как сделать, чтобы python видел библиотеку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте установить OpenCV с помощью менеджера пакетов [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html). В отличие от pip, conda устанавливает не только Python пакеты, но и бинарные версии их зависимостей.

```
$ wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
$ bash ./Miniconda-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
$ conda install opencv
```